# Scandit Websdk Javascript set orientation

Tags: javascript, camera, scandit

I am using scandit for my webapp Qrcode scanning. Everything is working fine but I am just stuck at how to set the size of the scandit-barcode-picker. I want it half the mobile screen in landscape mode.
I am not able to find any documentation regarding the set orientation.
Here is the way I have initialized.

HTML:

```
<div id="scandit-barcode-picker" style="max-height: 300px !important;"></div>
```

Javascript:

```
const licenseKey = SCANDIT_LICENSE;
let decoder;
ScanditSDK.configure(licenseKey, {
engineLocation: string = "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/scandit-sdk/build"
});

ScanditSDK.BarcodePicker.create(document.getElementById("scandit-barcode-picker"), {
    playSoundOnScan: true,
    vibrateOnScan: true,
}).then(function (barcodePicker) {
    decoder = barcodePicker;
    var scanSettings = new ScanditSDK.ScanSettings({
        enabledSymbologies: ["code128", "code39"],
        codeDuplicateFilter: 1000,
    });
    decoder.applyScanSettings(scanSettings);
    decoder.setPlaySoundOnScanEnabled(true);
    decoder.on("scan", function (scanResult) {
    barcode = scanResult.barcodes.pop();
    onScanned({
        format: ScanditSDK.Barcode.Symbology.toHumanizedName(barcode.symbology),
        code: barcode.data
    });
});
decoder.resumeScanning();
});
```

This is taking the height but also keeping the aspect ration. It is showing in portraint mode. I want it in landscape mode. Any help please?

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I work for Scandit

WebSDK BarcodePicker automatically fits and adapts to the given container element (in this case the `scandit-barcode-picker` div), so you just need to apply whatever styling logic you want to that element via CSS/JS independently from the library.

To achieve your goal you probably need something like

```css
@media screen and (orientation: landscape) {
  #scandit-barcode-picker {
    ...
  }
}
```

in your styles.